# How to get checkbox or radiobutton value in Inno Setup TNewCheckListBox?

Tags: checkbox, radio-button, inno-setup, checkboxlist, pascalscript

I thought it was something simple to code, but the fact is that I'm finally facing issue about getting back checked/unchecked value of checkboxes and radiobuttons in a `TNewCheckListBox`.

I tried to set the checkboxes and radiobutton as global instance so that I can easily access it in the `NextButtonClick` event.

But in this sample test I get

> Could not call proc.

```pascal
[Code]
var
  PageChoixComposants: TWizardPage;
  CB1, CB2: TNewCheckBox;
  OB1, OB2: TNewRadioButton; 

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;
begin
  PageChoixComposants := CreateCustomPage(
    wpWelcome, 'Custom wizard page controls', 'TNewCheckListBox');

  CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(PageChoixComposants);
  CheckListBox.Width := PageChoixComposants.SurfaceWidth;
  CheckListBox.Height := ScaleY(97);
  CheckListBox.Flat := True;
  CheckListBox.Parent := PageChoixComposants.Surface;
  CB1 := CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('CB1', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);
  OB1 := CheckListBox.AddRadioButton('CB1 OB1', '', 1, True, True, nil);
  OB2 := CheckListBox.AddRadioButton('CB1 OB2', '', 1, False, True, nil);
  CB2 := CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('CB2', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);
end;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if (CurPageID=PageChoixComposants.ID) then
    begin      
      if CB1.Checked = True then
        begin
          MsgBox('CB1 checked', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        end;
    end;
  Result := True;
end;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AddCheckBox` and `AddRadioButton` methods return `Integer`, not `TNewCheckBox`/`TNewRadioButton`.

*It's even surprising that your code compiles. It looks like some deficiency of a compiler.*

The returned number represents an index of the checkbox/radio button. Use the index along with `TNewCheckListBox.Checked` (or `.State`) property to query the checkbox/radio button state.

A correct code is:

```pascal
var
  PageChoixComposants: TWizardPage;
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;
  CB1, CB2: Integer;
  OB1, OB2: Integer; 

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  PageChoixComposants :=
    CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Custom wizard page controls', 'TNewCheckListBox');

  CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(PageChoixComposants);
  CheckListBox.Width := PageChoixComposants.SurfaceWidth;
  CheckListBox.Height := ScaleY(97);
  CheckListBox.Flat := True;
  CheckListBox.Parent := PageChoixComposants.Surface;
  CB1 := CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('CB1', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);
  OB1 := CheckListBox.AddRadioButton('CB1 OB1', '', 1, True, True, nil);
  OB2 := CheckListBox.AddRadioButton('CB1 OB2', '', 1, False, True, nil);
  CB2 := CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('CB2', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = PageChoixComposants.ID then
  begin      
    if CheckListBox.Checked[CB1] then
    begin
      MsgBox('CB1 checked', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```